# How to use Chart JS by Node JS?

Tags: node.js, cdn

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html

Official website says to use this line:

`npm install chart.js --save`

However all youtube tutorials copy-paste CDN link, and totally ignore the way to do it inside Node JS.

I insert chart code in my handlebars page and obviously get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined"

Comment: well you can use this command on your local computer too if you developing an app with, for example, Vue.js. Therefore you use VUE CLI and can install chart js with this command. so this command isnt made for the serverside

Comment: I am a raw beginner so I don't understand WHERE should I insert a code: 1) If in html - it doesnt recognize Chart instance. 2) If in app.js(in NodeJS) - I can't use ctx = getElementById() - it has to be inside script tag on a page.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [official documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html)

```
Common JS
    var Chart = require('chart.js');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});

Bundlers (Webpack, Rollup, etc.)
    import Chart from 'chart.js';
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
```

Comment: ctx will not recognized, because ctx = document.getElementById("MyChart") ... and theres no document in NodeJS app.js

Comment: Do you want to use frontend library at backend? Could you describe your task more detailed?